# How to disable code analysis in MSBuild target ClCompile?

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, code-analysis

When I build my projects via MSBuilds scripts, I obtain the following message during the work of `ClCompile` target: `Running Code Analysis for C/C++…`

Output of MSBuild looks like:

```
ClCompile:
  ....
  Source1.cpp
  Source2.cpp
  Running Code Analysis for C/C++…
```

After changing `<RunCodeAnalysis>` property in build scripts to false:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
</PropertyGroup>
```

this just disabled running `RunCodeAnalysis` MSBuild target, but it does not affect running code analysis in `ClCompile` target - it seems it should be disabled somewhere else.

How can I disable code analysis during execution of `ClCompile` target?

Comment: I'm guessing you are actually talking about the /analyze compiler option.  It is turned on by the `<EnablePREfast>` build property.

Comment: Thanks! It exactly what I was looked for, it reduced overall build time more then twice. It would be good if you move comment to answer and I accept it.

Comment: It is difficult to describe because there is separate target for code analysis and there is code analysis as a part of compilation - both emit messages concerning code analysis. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<EnablePREfast>` should be set up to `false`.

I have used the following code:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnablePREfast>false</EnablePREfast>
</PropertyGroup>
```

More info at [CL Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee862477.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In Project Property page, goto **Code Analysis** (the last one on left tree). There you can disable Code analysis feature. In VC10+, you just need to de-select second check box. In earlier versions, you set third property to No.