# Any MSBuild command line option to disable code analysis for c++ project dynamically?

Tags: c++, docker, jenkins, msbuild, code-analysis

I got following error when compiling the c++ project(code analysis enabled)with Build Tools 2017 in Windows container "windowservercore".

**Running Code Analysis for C/C++...**

**c1xx : error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated [C:\jenkins\workspace\ABC-DEV\ABC\ABC.vcxproj]**

**c1xx : fatal error C1250: Unable to load plug-in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\localespc.dll'. [C:\jenkins\workspace\ABC-DEV\ABC\ABC.vcxproj]**

Compile script:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"  C:\Work\ABC.sln /p:configuration=Release /p:platform=x64 /t:rebuild
```

I edited the ABC.vcxproj like below and error C2220 and C1250 are resolved.

```
<RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
<EnablePREfast>false</EnablePREfast>
```

but I tried following compiling command to disable code analysis dynamically but got a different error.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"  C:\Work\ABC.sln /p:configuration=Release /p:platform=x64 /p:RunCodeAnalysis=false /t:rebuild
```

**c1xx : fatal error C1253: Unable to load model file 'res://mspft140.dll/300'.**

Is there any MSBuild option to disable code analysis for c++ project without editing the project file?

---

Update:

Put Directory.Build.props into the ABC.sln file's directory does not disable the code analysis.

Directory.Build.props

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <EnablePREfast>false</EnablePREfast>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is the ABC.vcxproj after I ticked off checkbox "Enable Code Analysis on Build".

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
   <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
       <EnablePREfast>false</EnablePREfast>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Comment: It's more helpful to post the complete error. First off, why is some code file not generating an object file? (i.e. a *.obj files is not getting created).

Comment: For the reason why the edit in .vcxproj file worked but command-line failed:  The global property in command-line is used to **override** the values set in .xxproj file, it's different from real-defining in xx.xxproj file, we can't override a variable which is not defined. It won't work.  And you can easily check this point but a after-build target to output the RunCodeAnalysis property, it won't be `false`, it would be `empty`.

Comment: Thanks. Put Directory.Build.props into the ABC.sln file's directory does not disable the code analysis, pls see the updated question.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9448772/10910450), once the EnablePREfast is a property. But for now in VS2017, it's part of ClCompile Item, maybe that's why code analysis is not disable. I'm not sure if metadata of Clcompile item can override the one in project file, since directory.build.directory is used to override property always.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the second error was fixed by microsoft already:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/334430/unable-to-run-code-analysis-on-cmake-project.html.
So have you updated your visual studio 2019?

And you shouldn't suppress errors or warnings (especially in c++), where the runtime is especially fragile to crashes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any MSBuild option to disable code analysis for c++ project
>   without editing the project file?

Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets), you can use `Directory.Build.props` to define the `RunCodeAnalysis` property without modifying the .vcxproj file.

1.Create a .txt file and rename it as `Directory.Build.props`.

2.The content of it should be like:

```
    <Project>
         <PropertyGroup>
           <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
         </PropertyGroup>
         ...
        </Project>
```

(Disable the code analysis for all configurations and platforms)

Or something like:

```
<Project>
     <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
       <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
     </PropertyGroup>
     ...
</Project>
```

(Only disable the code analysis for build with `Release|x64` combination)

3.Put this file in your solution folder or put it to the path in your project's directory structure.